# How to fix POST is not function error in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have the following code an am getting a `POST is not function error`. How can I fix this?

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Post = require('../../models/Post');

router.all('/*',(req, res, next)=>{
    req.app.locals.layout='admin';
    next();
});

router.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    res.send('It  Works');
});

router.get('/create',(req, res)=>{
    res.render('admin/posts/create');
});`// router.post('/create',(req, res)=>{

//     res.send('worked');

// });

router.post('/create', (req, res)=>{
    let allowComments=true;
    if(req.body.allowComments){
        allowComments=true;   
    }else{
        allowComments=false;
    }
    Post({
            title: req.body.title,
            status: req.body.status,
            allowComments:allowComments,
            body: req.body.body
    });
    newPost.save().then(savedPost=>{
        res.redirect('/admin/posts');
    }).catch(error=>{
        console.log('could not post');
    });
    // console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports=router;
```

And `Post` model is

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const PostSchema = new Schema({ // user:{ // // }, 
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    default: 'public'
  },
  allowComments: {
    type: Boolean,
    require: require
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  }
});
module.exports = -mongoose.model('posts', PostSchema);
```

Comment: Include `../../models/Post` file to question too.

Comment: const mongoose=require('mongoose');



const Schema=mongoose.Schema;



const PostSchema = new Schema({



    // user:{


    //


    // },



    title:{


        type:String,


        required:true
    },

    status:{
        type:String,
        default:'public'
    },

    allowComments:{
        type:Boolean,
        require:require
    },

    body:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    }

});

module.exports=-mongoose.model('posts',PostSchema);

Comment: your file is Post.js or post.js ?

Comment: Why is there a '-' sign after 'module.exports ='?

Comment: Hello All,

My code is again giving me an error i.e "Could not post"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have - sign here

```
module.exports = -mongoose.model('posts', PostSchema);
```

That would make your import a `number` (actually NaN)

```
const Post = require('../../models/Post');
```

And a number is not a function.

```js
const module = {}

function foo(){
}

module.exports = foo
console.log(module)

module.exports = -foo
console.log(module)
```

Comment: can anybody help me posting the data using post function